# Macro that checks std::vector requirements

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++03

I have an immutable class - all members are `const`. Since it's immutable, there is no default constructor and no copy assignment. In C++11 I use this class in an `std::vector` with no problems.

Now I need to compile the code in an environment that only supports C++03. Obviously my class is not [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable), and C++03 `std::vector` requires this, I can't put instances of the class in a vector.

Since the code will be maintained on C++11-friendly compilers, and only compiled and run on a C++03 environment, I thought the easiest way to make this work was to *remove the `const` modifier in C++03*. This will make the class CopyAssignable and will work in C++03. In C++11 I still want the class to be immutable, of course.

I went over the long list of [Boost C++11 Macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported), but couldn't find one that will tell me if std::vector requires CopyAssignable types.

Is there a way to do that, or should I just introduce my own macro that will be set during compilation?

Comment: _"Since it's immutable, there is no default constructor."_ Eehm what?

Comment: Well, all instances created with the default constructors will be identical, since there's no way to set their values to anything other than the default. So no default constructor.

Comment: While it can be a reasonable design choice, it's not a logical conclusion that follows from the premise. I understand orlp's confusion. "It's immutable, so I didn't add a default ctor" would be a more accurate description. What's less understandable is the lack of a copy ctor. `4`  may be immutable, but I certainly can copy it.

Comment: @MSalters There's (presumably) a copy constructor. It's the assignment operator that's missing. But yeah, making immutable structures nonassignable is not necessarily appropriate in a language like C++ which has value-typed rather than reference-typed UDT variables.

Comment: Well, C++ doesn't prejudice against reference-like UDT's. They're UD, after all. But the C++03 container classes did expect values, yes. Without an `emplace_back`, there's no good support for reference-like behavior.

Comment: Yes, there is a copy constructor. The choice to make the class immutable was a compromise, because the class has evolved and it had existing users.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to just check the C++ version; `#if __cplusplus < 201103L` should be sufficient. Presumably there's no Boost macro checking this because all C++11 compilers are compliant in this respect.